# Azure Service Bus public endpoints without authorization?

Tags: azure, servicebus

Hey I am using Windows Azure Service Bus, but as soon as I try to connect to my end point it says error 401 (which is http unauthorized) and this end point is going to serve a simple web-page on which the rest of application runs.

(Basically the endpoint is streaming my screens live video- i did it as a proof of concept)

So is it possible to have this end-point accessible without any access token ?

Comment: Please provide better description, exact configuration (what exact features of all that Azure SErvice Bus has you use and how - configuration), relevant code snippets, etc.

Comment: @astaykov I am simply using the service bus with webRelayClient so that i can make an http request through a browser to get access to code running in my browser.